# All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Courier

Tags: c#, itext, itext7, pdfa

I have code in place for iText 7.1.5 that fills an AcroForm inside an existing PDF/A document. For that, I also create a PdfFont.
Now, I am trying to upgrade from iText 7.1.5 to 7.2.5 but it seems there has been a change in 7.1.7 that is breaking my current implementation and resulting in the above error.

Current Code looks like this (simplified):

```
using (var pdfDocument = new PdfADocument(pdfReader, writer))
{
    PdfFont fontCourier = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(fontBytes,
        PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.FORCE_EMBEDDED); // 2nd parameter used to be 'true' in 7.1.x

    var acroForm = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
    var field = acroForm.GetField(formField.Name);
    field.SetValue(fieldValue, fontCourier, fontSize);
}
```

On disposal of the pdfDocument, I am getting the exception that my font is not embedded, which used to work with 7.1.5 and went through all validations I performed on the resulting document with other tools.

Edit: I have also tried to use an already embedded version of the Courier font by iterating through all objects of the document to find fonts, check their names and whether they are embedded.
Unfortunately, this gets me the same exception, which seems odd, considering it should already be embedded.

Comment: No annotations, just the values of the acro form that are being set (and XMP meta data). And the font is provided, so my understanding is that iText should embed it. And it did up until 7.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Courier is one of the standard fonts, see PDF specification ISO 32000-2 paragraph 9.6.2.2.
It means that the font is "embedded" into pdf processors, like Adobe Acrobat.
If you want to use Courier, create font by the following way:

```
PdfFont fontCourier = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);
```

Comment: That would be right if I was not trying to create a PDF/A document where every font being used must be embedded. And trying to embed a standard font leads to another exception: _Standard fonts cannot be embedded._

Comment: In iText architecture standard fonts are special (let's say "abstract") fonts which can't be embedded by sense, because iText doesn't render PDF, but just create them.
Find proper real font for standard fonts is a viewer task.
So, i would suggest you to use non-standard font, and in that way iText will embed it.

Comment: Yes, and that should work as well when I provide my own Courier font but it doesn't, hence my original question.